# How to add tax to Stripe subscription using Laravel Cashier (4.2)

Tags: php, laravel-4, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'd like to apply tax to the subscription I have just swapped the user to. Here is my attempt:

```
protected function swapToYearlyPlan(){
    $company = Auth::user()->company;
    $customer = $company->subscription()->getStripeCustomer();

    $company->subscription('Gold Annual Plan')->swap();

    // This doesn't seem to work -- no error message or anything.
    $company->subscription()->tax_percent = 5;

    return 'Upgraded to Gold Annual Plan w/ tax!!';
}
```

I looked through the Laravel Cashier files and wasn't able to find any code relating to taxes whatsoever in the `StripeGateway.php` file. My ultimate fear is that it can't be done in this version of Laravel Cashier.

Comment: So what is actually your question?

Comment: @hotzst I updated the question to be more clear. According to the documentation, there is a `tax_percent` attribute that you can set on a user's subscription.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, it looks like 4.2 doesn't seem to support this feature out of the box. You must separately add tax to an invoice as a separate line item.

I found [this post](https://www.tender.io/blog/stripe-tax-calculation) helpful.